# How to change the dropdown backgroundColor of an MUI 5 TextField select?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

As you can see from the image above, the background color of the dropdown needs to be changed. I'd like to change the white to black.

Here's my code:

```
const styles={ 
  textField:{
    '& .MuiPopover-paper':{
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    }
  }
}

...

<TextField select id='version' label='Version' variant='outlined' sx={styles.textField}>
  <MenuItem value={10}>1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>3</MenuItem>
</TextField>
```

I have tried many variations of `'.MuiPopover-paper'` none seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to style the underlying menu you can pass in `SelectProps` to the `TextField`.

```
<TextField
  select
  id="version"
  label="Version"
  variant="outlined"
  SelectProps={{
    MenuProps: {
      sx: styles.textField,
    },
  }}
>
```

I changed the styles object accordingly:

```
const styles = {
  textField: {
    ".MuiList-root": {
      backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: I also discovered `'.MuiInputBase-input':{color:'wheat', ':hover':{color:'blue'}}` controls the input colors.

Comment: Thank you for the addition. I often find it tricky to style deeply nested MUI components.